# Bind multiple columns of radio buttons in a table (grouped for each row)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

(I'm no expert on MVC, just saying)
I need to render a `<table>` that contains 4 columns:

Name

No Access

Viewer

File manager

The last 3 are booleans, and need to be bound to a radio button, and this radio button needs to group them for each row.

I know many different ways to display this in the view, but not sure the best way to ensure the data gets submitted back to the Controller properly.

Model:

```
public class DetailModel 
{ 
    //this displays the user information
    public Users_SelectByUserId User { get; set; }
    //This is what builds the Table with the 4 columns.
    public List<UserMinistryRef_SelectByUserID> MinistryRef { get; set; }

}
```

--

```
public class UserMinistryRef_SelectByUserID
{
    public int UserRecordId { get; set; }
    public int MinistryId { get; set; }
    public bool Minadmin { get; set; }
    public bool Updater { get; set; }
    public bool Viewer { get; set; }
    public string mname { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to display, and have the ability for these to populate back to the controller properly? I've tried to iterate through the MinistryRef collection, but I didn't get much luck with that, couldn't get it working with Razor while looping though the collection, and binding to a 3rd party grid control just turned out to be quite hectic.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track...

```
 @foreach (UserMinistryRef_SelectByUserID ministry in Model.MinistryRef)
            { 
                <tr>
                    <td>@ministry.mname</td>
                    ***NOte the below @Helpers are not supposed to work, just trying to show what I'm hoping to achieve.
                    <td>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model.MinistryRef.MinAdmin == true)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Html.RadioButtonFor(Model.MinistryRef.Viewer == true)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Html.RadioButtonFor(Model.MinistryRef.Viewer == false && Model.MinistryRef.MinAdmin == false)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use an int abstraction to control the radio button group like this:

model

```
public class UserMinistryRef_SelectByUserID
{
 public int UserRecordId { get; set; }
 public int MinistryId { get; set; }
 public bool Minadmin { get; set; }
 public bool Updater { get; set; }
 public bool Viewer { get; set; }
 public string mname { get; set; }
 public int AccessRights { get; set; } //0 = viewer, 1 = updater, 2 = minadmin
}
```

view

```
@{ int count = 0; }
@foreach (UserMinistryRef_SelectByUserID ministry in Model.MinistryRef)
{
 <tr>
  <td>@ministry.mname</td>
  <td>
   <input name="MinistryRef[@(count)].AccessRights" type="radio" value="0" @if(ministry.Viewer){<text>checked="checked"</text>} /> 
  </td>
  <td>
   <input name="MinistryRef[@(count)].AccessRights" type="radio" value="1" @if(ministry.Updater){<text>checked="checked"</text>} /> 
  </td>
  <td>
   <input name="MinistryRef[@(count)].AccessRights" type="radio" value="2" @if(ministry.Minadmin){<text>checked="checked"</text>} /> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 count++;
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult action( DetailModel vm )
{
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
  foreach( var min in vm.MinistryRef )
  {
   switch( min.AccessRights )
   {
    case 0: /* Viewer */
    case 1: /* Updater */
    case 2: /* Minadmin */
   }
  }
 }

 return RedirectToAction("SomeHttpGet");
}
```